# How to use java.time.Instant with Swagger 2.x?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a REST endpoint in my java webapp that accepts an Instant as a query parameter as seen in the code below

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response getHistory(
    @QueryParam("beforeTime")
    Instant beforeTime,

    @QueryParam("afterTime")
    Instant afterTime) {
    ...
}
```

This worked well under swagger 1.x, but when we switch to swagger 2.x the objects of `Instant` are showing up as `$int64` instead of a date-time field. What can I do with the swagger annotations to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the @ApiParam annotation to fix this issue. Setting the type to `date-time` and format to `java.time.Instant` fixed the issue.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response getHistory(
    @QueryParam("beforeTime")
    @ApiParam(type="date-time", format = "java.time.Instant")
    Instant beforeTime,

    @QueryParam("afterTime")
    @ApiParam(type="date-time", format = "java.time.Instant")
    Instant afterTime) {
    ...
}
```